# Creating observable from another observable

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift

I would like to create Observable object of User. This is my structure

```
import Foundation

struct User {
    let email: String
    let username: String
}
```

When i do network request I get response of type Observable<[String:Any]>, that works fine, but I have no idea how to transform that into Observable<[User]>. I tried

```
func loadUsers() -> Observable<[User]> {
        return fetchUserData(cUser: Master.users).map(([String : Any]) throws -> [User])
    }
```

But I get this error

```
Cannot convert value of type '(([String : Any]) throws -> [User]).Type' to expected argument type '([String : Any]) throws -> [User]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where `Observable` comes from, there's no class like that in Foundation. Combine has observables, but they're not called that there, they're various types of publishers. Are you using another library like RxSwift?

For the sake of getting you closer to answering the question, let's imagine that fetchUserData returns an array instead.

`map` needs to take a function that will transform the input from `[String:Any]` to `User`. In your case, something like

```swift
    fetchUserData(...).compactMap { dict in
        // I am making "username" and "email" up below,
        // you did not mention which keys would exist in the dictionary.
        if let username = dict["username"] as? String,
           let email = dict["email"] as? String {
            return User(email:email, username:username)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

I used [`compactMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap), which does the same thing as `map`, except that when you return an optional (`User?` in this case), it removes the nil entries.

The reactive framework you're using will have similar calls to do the same thing on Observable, on Publisher, etc. They will also allow you to throw an error instead of returning nil, but they all handle it differently (Combine includes the error type in the type of the Publisher, for example).

Comment: Ayy thank you so much, although I haven't given full info on what I'm planing to do. I'm using RxSwift and I would like to use my structure as it confronts to protocol codable to place given varibables automatically from Observable<[String:Any]>, and create new Observable of type User

Comment: If you declare it as conforming to Codable (which you still have to do with `: Codable`, but it will fill in the implementation for you), you still have to find a way from `[String:Any]` to your object. Codable means it can decode with a decoder, and you have to have a decoder object somewhere. As another example, if you received Data instead of `[String:Any]`, you could say that it's JSON and use a JSONDecoder.

Comment: Codable/Decodable and Coder/Decoder are focused on: given a bunch of bytes (a `Data`), 1) decode this to a format of some type, like a JSON or property list structure, and 2) then pluck the information you are interested in from certain places (see CodingKey) inside those structures and create an object with the right information. If I understand you correctly, you want to do only the second half of this. [This project looks like a way to do that](https://github.com/elegantchaos/DictionaryCoding). Usually, I would expect a method named fetchUserData to do either both or none of these halves.